# Why does PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute() not work in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

In .NET 4(.5) there is this amazing Attribute: `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute`, I want to use it in SharePoint 2013 so I don't have to edit the app_start method in the global.asax file directly.

Since SP2013 runs the correct version of .NET I assumed that this attribute would just work... but this seems not to be the case.

Has anyone figured out how to use it yet? or explain why it cannot work?

Original Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14374750/1399964